# examples of shared libraries not in c/c++?

Tags: shared-libraries, ffi

Many languages make it possible to produce a shared library that can be called from C. And since it can be called from C it can potentially be called via a foreign function interface from just about any language.

Some languages that support this are: Fortran, Ada, Pascal, Objective C, D, OCaml, Haskell, Go, Rust... 
(Just because it's possible doesn't mean it's necessarily practical/easy/nice.)

Even so, the vast majority of shared libraries found on a common linux system seem to be written in c or c++. Are there any examples of shared libraries written in other languages that are widely used (as in not just an experiment)?

Answer (score 2):

Firefox uses Rust shared libraries. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Building_Firefox_with_Rust_code) for more details.